# Авторизация на сайте в Python с помощью Grab

Tags: python, парсер, авторизация, grab

Не могу авторизоваться через модуль Grab в Python на сайте moikrug.ru, кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем дело? Пишу вот так

```
grab = Grab(log_file='out.html')
grab.go('https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmoikrug'
        '.yandex.ru')
grab.set_input("login", login)
grab.set_input("passwd", password)
grab.submit()
s1 = grab.response.unicode_body()
```

В итоге выводится незалогиненая страница

Answer (score 1):

Удачно авторизовался по этой ссылке: https://passport.yandex.ru/auth

С вашей ссылкой возникала ошибка с таймаутом, ссылка точно правильная?

Comment: Спустя полгода, спасибо

Comment: хех :) лучше поздно, чем никогда :)

Знаете, не всегда получается авторизоваться на какие-то сайты, возможно дело в каких-то скриптах. Я тогда использовал Webkit, который есть в Qt -- QWebkit. Для питона это может быть модуль PySide